# How do I compare data to previous year, matching on the same day of the week?

Tags: google-bigquery

So I want to compare the current year's sales data with the previous year data, based on the same day of the week. If the date is 2019-05-08, the day to compare to should be 2019-05-09 because they are both Monday.
For example, if my sales table is like this:

| date | store | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-01 | US | 1000 |
| 2023-07-03 | UK | 2000 |
| 2022-07-02 | US | 950 |
| 2022-07-04 | UK | 1800 |

I already tried this:

```
WITH
cte AS (
SELECT
COALESCE(c.date, DATE_ADD(p.date, INTERVAL 52 WEEK)) AS date,
COALESCE(c.store_name, p.store_name) AS store_name,
SUM(c.revenue) AS current_year_revenue,
SUM(p.revenue) AS prev_year_revenue
FROM
`_sales` c
FULL OUTER JOIN
`_sales` p
ON
c.date = DATE_ADD(p.date, INTERVAL 52 WEEK)
AND c.store_name = p.store_name
WHERE
(c.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE('Europe/Budapest'), INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
AND CURRENT_DATE('Europe/Budapest'))
GROUP BY
1,
2)
SELECT
*
FROM
cte
ORDER BY
date,
store_name
```

What I want is this:

| date | store | current_revenue | prev_revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-01 | US | 1000 | 950 |
| 2023-07-03 | UK | 2000 | 1800 |

If I used this code to query the data by each day, current_revenue is correct. However the previous year's revenue would be incorrect. I'm very confused on how this could happen.
Obviously, there is something wrong with the way I create the comparison but I couldn't find out where.

Answer (score 0):

I would join the table on itself using the year, the week number and the day name as keys:

```
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT CAST('2023-07-01' AS date) AS date_, 'US' AS store, 1000 AS revenue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-07-03','UK', 2000
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-07-02', 'US', 950
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-07-04', 'UK', 1800
  ),

date_extract AS (
SELECT 
  *,
  EXTRACT(year from date_) AS year, 
  EXTRACT(week from date_) AS week_number,
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK from date_) AS day_name
  FROM sample_data
  )

SELECT
x.date_, x.year, x.store, x.revenue, y.revenue as last_year_revenue
FROM date_extract as x 
LEFT JOIN date_extract as y
ON x.store=y.store 
   AND x.year = y.year+1 
   AND x.week_number = y.week_number 
   AND x.day_name = y.day_name
WHERE y.revenue IS NOT NULL
```